# Number of ways of picking letters and numbers

Tags: combinatorics

> Some codes are generated consisting of 3 letters from A-Z (repetition allowed) followed by 2 digits from 1-9 (repetition allowed). Find the number of codes that consist of exactly one vowel and exactly one even digit.

I got

$$\left(\binom{5}{1}\cdot3\cdot21^2\right)\cdot\left(4\cdot5\cdot2\right)$$

but the answer says

$$\binom{5}{1}\cdot21\cdot20\cdot3!\cdot4\cdot5\cdot2 + \binom{5}{1}\cdot21\binom{3}{2}\cdot4\cdot5\cdot2$$

The difference between my attempt and the answer is the way the letters are choosen.

In my attempt, I selected the one vowel, permute its position, and then select the remaining two non-vowels. Is this method of counting wrong?

Comment: The problem with your computation is that you didn't take into account the positioning of the consonants. The first term in the correct answer is the case where the two consonants are different; the second where they are the same.

Comment: I think 'the answer' is wrong.  They have double-counted the ones with two different consonants.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Some codes are generated consisting of 3 letters from A-Z followed by 2 digits from 1-9. Find the number of codes that consist of exactly one vowel and exactly one even digit.

**Repetition not allowed**
$$N=\underbrace{\binom51}_{\text{vowel.}}\underbrace{\binom{21}2}_{\text{rest two letters.}}\underbrace{3!}_{\text{arrangement of letters.}}\underbrace{\binom41}_{\text{even number.}}\underbrace{\binom51}_{\text{rest numbers.}}\underbrace{2!}_{\text{arrangement of numbers.}}$$

**Repetition allowed**
$$N=\binom51\left( \binom{21}23!+21^2\frac{3!}{2!}\right)\binom41\binom512!$$

Comment: But this does not take into account cases where the consonants are repeated

Comment: @LeeYiyuan i overlooked repetition allowed

Comment: @LeeYiyuan see the edit